# Switching the limit and integral Criteria

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does there exist a sequence of function $f_n$ on $[a, b]$ such that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent, $f_n$ is not continuous, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x) \mathop{dx} \neq \int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \mathop{dx}?$$

In particular, can we switch the integral and limit whenever $f_n$ is uniformly convergent or do we need $f_n$ to also be continuous? If there does exist such a sequence of functions, please provide an example.

Comment: I do not believe continuity of the $f_n$ is required, just (Riemann) integrability on $[a,b]$. One must show that $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ is integrable, then the same proof shows that we may interchange the limit with the integral.

Answer (score 1):

*No* because of the following theorem:

> If $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty }$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions defined on a compact interval $I$ which uniformly converge with limit $f$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and its integral can be computed as the limit of the integrals of the $f_{n}$:
>   $$
> \int _{I}f=\lim _{n\to \infty }\int _{I}f_{n}.
> $$

There is no continuity assumption in the theorem here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about riemann integrals.
The $f_n$ don't need to be continous. But you need that they are riemann integrable. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability).